# How to create multiple reactions?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I was making this media channel where you could send media, and reactions would pop up, from really happy about it to really sad/angry about it. Here's my code:

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.channel.name === "media") {
      message.react('')
          .then(() => { 
              message.react('')
          });{ 
          };
  }
  if (message.channel.name === "media") {
      message.react('')
          .then(() => { 
              message.react('')
          });{ 
          };
  }
  if (message.channel.name === "media") {
     message.react('')
         .then(() => { 
            message.react('')
        });{ 
        };
  }
  if (message.channel.name === "media") {
     message.react('')
         .then(() => { 
            message.react('')
        });{ 
        };
  }
});
```

Can someone possibly tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us some more information first? Are you getting any erros or is the code just not behaving like intended? Which discord.js version are you using? (If you're using 13+ you should change `client.on('message',` to `client.on('messageCreate',`) Is there anything else you've tried?

Comment: I've tried putting them in separate but then they go out of order, and I need it to be in a specific order.

Comment: So the reactions are getting added to the target message, but in the wrong order?

Comment: Oh! It works now, I just have to switch around the reactions, I just put them in the wrong order, lol 

Comment: Thanks for your help! I forgot about MessageCreate, so this helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

From https://stackoverflow.com/users/13685706/toasty Toasty

The correction was to change `client.on('message',` to `client.on('messageCreate',`

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with your question though...